# Is there an interpreter available that will convert infix to RPN?

Tags: pstricks

I am starting to use PSTricks a bit more, and have been looking at the `\psVolume` command defined in `pst-func` package.  My problem is with Reverse Polish Notation.  Is there an interpreter available that will convert infix to RPN?

Comment: Do you want the interpreter to be in TeX? Otherwise I think this might be a bit off-topic here.

Comment: Apologies!  It would need to be in Tex.  Thanks

Comment: I have just googled your suggestion - it is exactly what I want!  Thank you!

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer, don't forget to check it by clicking the check mark link at the bottom of the down vote arrow. Doing this is important to avoid many open question and also to increase your acceptance percentage. Other people will usually be reluctant to help members with low acceptance percentage.

Answer (score 4):

As `\psVolume` defined in `pst-func` cannot accept `algebraic` option, you need to use `infix-RPN` package as follows:

### Simpler Example

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{infix-RPN,pst-func}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=10pt\relax

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-2)(5,2.5)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(0,-2)(3,2.5)
    \infixtoRPN{x^0.5}%
    \psVolume[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=magenta!30](0,4){10}{\RPN}
    \psline{->}(4,0)(5,0)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The usage is so simple: invoke `\infixtoRPN` then use the output `\RPN`.

**WARNING** : Trigonometry functions work in degree (not radian) if they are expressed in RPN notation.
For example:

- `\psplot{0}{3.1415}{x sin}` means you want to plot the sine from 0 degree to 3.1415 degree.
- `\psplot{0}{3.1415}{180 3.1415 div x mul sin}` means you plot the sine from 0 degree to *about* 180 degree.

### Simple Example with Trigonometry

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{infix-RPN,pst-func}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=10pt\relax

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-3)(7,3)  
    \def\f(#1){sin(180/\psPi*#1)+1.2}%
    \infixtoRPN{\f(x)}%
    \psVolume[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=magenta!30](0,\psPiTwo){15}{\RPN}
    \psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptscriptstyle]
            {->}(0,0)(0,-2.75)(6.75,2.75)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \rput[bl](*{\psPi\space 2 div} {\f(x)+0.2}){$y=sin(x)+1.2$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```